# javascript resize background image

Tags: javascript, background-image

Is it possible to resize a background image on load using javascript?  I don't care about dynamically resizing the image according to window size or anything, I just want to take large images and resize them to a specific width and height so that the full image fits inside a specific layout.

WORK AROUND:

I did what the people below said and used a regular  tag that I sized accordingly and positioned absolutely in the containing div.  I then used the z-index property to push it to the background.

```
img.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: See edit for my work-around solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to [reliably, x-browser] scale a background image in any way at this point, but it is available in CSS3 ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size)) so hope exists for the future.

Use an actual  if you want to scale, in which case yes of course you can resize whenever you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Background images cannot be resized.

Your best call is to use an `<img>` with `position:absolute`